# Return table with separate columns from function

Tags: postgresql, functions

I have this function, it's simple enough:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function()
RETURNS TABLE(
        id INTEGER,
        organization_id INTEGER,
        email_address CHARACTER VARYING
)
AS $BODY$
        SELECT id, organization_id, email_address FROM users;

$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The output of this functions gives me something that looks like this:

```
> SELECT test_function();                                                                                                                                                                                                          test_function 
---------------
 (1,1,test)
 (3,1,test2)
 (4,2,2test)
```

When I run the query by itself, I expect to get something more like this:

```
> select id, organization_id, email_address FROM users;
 id | organization_id | email_address 
----+-----------------+---------------
  1 |               1 | test
  3 |               1 | test2
  4 |               2 | 2test
```

How can I get a similar result back like that so I can parse it in a SQL function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get decomposed, separate columns, call the table function with:

```
SELECT * FROM test_function();
```

But you also have sneaky **naming conflicts**. The column names listed in the [`RETURNS TABLE` clause are implicit `OUT` parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE), visible in every SQL statement in the function body. Avoid using names that conflict with column names and/or table-qualify all possibly conflicting table column names in the function body. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function()
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, organization_id int, email_address varchar) AS
$func$
SELECT u.id, u.organization_id, u.email_address FROM users u;
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

See: [Variable Substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) in the manual.